# i keep getting Undefined or Error with my .env file

Tags: reactjs, .env

Im using: React TypeScript,Dotenv,Macair M2

Repo(https://github.com/hashlips-lab/nft-erc721-collection)

I want to access process.env.ALCHEMY_GEORLI_API_KEY from an .env file in Folder2.

Instructions by Author to install dependencies for each folder this way: "cd smart-contract; yarn; yarn compile; cd ../minting-dapp; yarn; yarn build"

to run dapp in the browser

- cd minting-dapp
- yarn dev-server

My code in minting-dapp >> dapp.tsx

```
import * as dotenv from '../../../../smart-contract/node_modules/dotenv';
dotenv.config();
//for the purpose of testing
console.log(process.env.ALCHEMY_GEORLI_API_KEY)
```

Code in smart-contract  >> .env code:

```
COLLECTION_URI_PREFIX=something
BLOCK_EXPLORER_API_KEY=something
ALCHEMY_GEORLI_API_KEY=somethin
ALCHEMY_MAINNET_API_KEY=something
```

-- Folder structure --

```
Main Project folder:

minting-dapp (Folder1)
 -node_modules
 -public
 -src
   -scripts
     -react
       -dapp.tsx << my code here 
smart-contract  (Folder2)  << .env file is here
 -node_modules
 -scripts
   -reveal.tsx
 -hardhat.config
 -.env
```

Scripts in Folder 2 accessing the variable this way:

hardhat.config.ts //(script1)

```
import fs from 'fs';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
import { HardhatUserConfig, task } from 'hardhat/config';
dotenv.config();
```

reveal.tsx   // (script2) // No import at all is used

```
if (undefined === process.env.COLLECTION_URI_PREFIX || process.env.COLLECTION_URI_PREFIX === 'ipfs://__CID___/') {
throw '\x1b[31merror\x1b[0m ' + 'Please add the URI prefix to the ENV configuration before running this command.';
}
```

1.When I try my code I get this error:

> Module build failed: Module not found:
> "./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js" contains a reference to the file "fs".
> This file can not be found, please check it for typos or update it if the file got moved.

2. When I try like “script1” it gives underlying error "Cannot find module 'dotenv'
3. When I try like “script2” I get the undefined return

** Note: dotEnv packaged is installed in Folder2

UPDATE: it seems the thing im trying to do will expose my API key to the Front-End which defeat the whole purpose of .env i guess, newbie mistake. i'll start looking for another solution. maybe define it in the server.

Comment: Why are you importing from node_modules? Why not`import * as dotenv from 'dotenv'`?

Comment: When i tried that it gave underlying error "Cannot find module 'dotenv' so i had to make the path that way

Comment: See https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-custom-environment-variables. You probably shouldn't be importing it like that.

Comment: The refrenced URL is using Built-in environment variable, i need to keep the code's project with the used 'dotEnv package'

Comment: There's not enough information here to understand your situation. How are you building and running this? How did you install dotenv? What is `smart-contract`? The fact that it's 4 directories up and has its own `node_modules` feels super unusual.

Comment: You're correct. i updated it with more info. I hope this is more clearer

Comment: Any updates here? I have the same problem.